# No C# project is currently loaded. Please create a C# project in order to debug

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

I'm having trouble with creating a C# project in VS Code.

I installed .NET 8.0.100 and made a new console app by using command

```
dotnet new console
```

but when I press the <kbd>F5</kbd> key on that `.cs` file, I get this error:

> No C# project is currently loaded. Please create a C# project in order to debug

I searched lots of cases and I found some difference. When I search ".NET:Generate ..." in VS Code search tab (the center-top of VS Code app) nothing happens (I can't find .NET menus when I search them). And that's why in my project, there is no `.vscode` folder.

Can anybody help me?

[image: vscode1]

[image: vscode2]

I don't know what to do.

Comment: I'm sorry it's my first time that post in StackOverflow so images that i uploaded don't appear but have to click it. And also I installed vscode c# extensions.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure, but I think you need to install [C# Dev Kit](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-dotnettools.csdevkit) and  Microsoft's other extensions to work with C#. Did you install C# debugger extensions?

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/csharp/get-started
I follwed this tutorial (C# dev kit tutorial) and finally I can make compile by pressing F5. But even though, the ".NET:Generate ..." menu is still missing and ".vscode" folder is missing. But.. whatever! I can compile my code!